# google script, merge the data from different sheets based on common values in a common column

Tags: google-apps-script, match

Hi guys I have an example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OFEbF1Ng3z2Ry8G5PD206l-QsSVJFilif7i0S2X7lYk/edit?usp=sharing

I want to compare the data in Sheet "TB".Column C and data in Sheet "2".Column U
And if there is any match, the data in Sheet "2".Column W will be displayed in Sheet "TB".Column J in the correct rows

This is what I have done so far:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var sstb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tb");
  var a = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(a).getRange("B1").setValue(a);

  var lrSVals = ss.getRange("U8:U").getValues();
  var lrS = lrSVals.filter(String).length;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(a).getRange("U1").setValue(lrS);

  var lrTB = sstb.getLastRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tb").getRange("C1").setValue(lrTB);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tb").getRange(1,6+2*a).setValue(a);

  //matching and display matched results
  for (x1 = 8; x1<= lrS;x1++) {
    for (x2 = 6; x2<= lrTB; x2++) {
      if ((ss.getRange(x1,21).getValue()) == (sstb.getRange(x2,3).getValue())) {

        x4 = ss.getRange(x1,23).getValue();
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tb").getRange(x2,6+2*a).setValue(-x4);
      }

    }
  }

}
```

However it takes really long for google spreadsheet to run the script.

I found an add-on names Power Tools. It has Merge Sheet function which is similar to what im doing.
However it leaves many "0" in empty cells and it also takes a very long time to finish the required steps

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be faster, you should avoid so much call on Range.getValue() method, cause it's cost a lot of ressource and time. Instead, make a big call in the beginning and work on your data from some arrays. Here is a possible solution:

```
  function myFunction2(){

  // Get your spreadsheet and the sheets "TB" and "2"
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetTB = ss.getSheetByName("TB");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("2");

  // Get the range on sheet "TB"
  var tabTB = sheetTB.getRange(5, 3, sheetTB.getLastRow(), 8);

  // Get the values to compare
  var dataTB = tabTB.getValues();
  var data2 = sheet2.getRange(8, 21, sheet2.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < dataTB.length; i++){

    for(var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++){

      // Compare data: if they're the same, put the value 
      if(dataTB[i][0].localeCompare(data2[j][0]) == 0){

        dataTB[i][7] = data2[j][2];

      }

    }

  }

  // Take the modified tab and put it on the spreadsheet
  tabTB.setValues(dataTB);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip on avoiding getValue method!
However, your code doesnt seem to work. I fully understand your code and I really dont know where is the problem.
Could you check it again?

Comment: Can you precise on which point the code is not working ? Edit: If you launch it as it, you must change the function name, or you'll have conflict with your own solution.

Comment: Hi, I have check the code. The problems should be in one of these " itemTB[7] = item2[2];" or "tabTB.setValues(dataTB);"

Comment: It's seems that my for statement got some trouble. I fix it in the answer.